# asyncio gather scheduling order guarantee

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Is it guaranteed that coroutines that are arguments to `asyncio.gather` will 
be scheduled with order preserved? Consider following example:

```
import asyncio

async def coro(i):
    print('{i} finished'.format(i=i))

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
            coro(0),
            coro(1),
            coro(2),
            coro(3),
            coro(4),
    )

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

and the result:

```
0 finished
1 finished
2 finished
3 finished
4 finished
```

Comment: It is definitely not guaranteed that they will be scheduled (or executed) in a particular order. What _is_ guaranteed is that the _results_ of the awaitables passed to `gather` will come in the same order as the corresponding awaitables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, at least from the source code of the cpython implementation, they will be scheduled in the order. The list of co-routines is iterated and a task added to the loop for each one of them one by one. Although I do not see in which scenario the scheduling guarantee becomes important. There is no guarantee the loop will execute them in order, nor any gurantee they will complete in that order. I think this will depend on the implementation details of the specific loop and the nature of the code. For example, try adding a asyncio.sleep(1) to the co-routine before the print.

Comment: I added `asyncio.sleep(1)` before print and ran OP's code several times. In Py3.7 the order of output was always same as they are in `asyncio.gather` call. While in Py3.6 they are always different. That makes me think is there something in Py3.7 that at least starts execution in order? It cannot be a coincidence that every run in py3.7 prints the output in order while every run in 3.6 produces a different output.

Answer (score 38):

[From Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently)

> *awaitable asyncio.gather(*aws, loop=None, return_exceptions=False)*
>
> Run awaitable objects in the aws sequence concurrently.
>
> If any awaitable in aws is a coroutine, it is automatically scheduled
> as a Task.
>
> If all awaitables are completed successfully, the result is an
> aggregate list of returned values. **The order of result values
> corresponds to the order of awaitables in aws.**

So the order of result values is preserved, but the execution order is not.

Comment: @VlanBezden The output pasted by OP above is from a `print` within a coroutine. So the output above shows the order of execution, and not the order collected by `asyncio.gather`. I tried the above code by adding `asyncio.sleep(1)` before the `print`. Py3.7 always printed them in order, while the output always differed for Py3.6. Is there something in Py3.7 that at least starts execution in order, which is not in Py3.6?

Answer (score 4):

There is one interesting corner case where order breaks down at least in Python 3.6.

Let's take an example like this:

```
import asyncio

async def main():
    data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

    async def aiter(iterable):
        for v in iterable:
            yield v

    aiterable = aiter(data)
    aiterables = [aiterable] * 8

    values = await asyncio.gather(
        *[it.__anext__() for it in aiterables])
    
    assert values == data, f'{values} != {data}'

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Approximate result in Py36:

```
AssertionError: [7, 6, 3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 1] != [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

This behavior looks logical, since `__anext__()` coroutines are executed in arbitrary order. However, in Py37+ the code works fine and output list order is preserved. I didn't find any mention of this in the documentation.